# Nginx not caching requests coming through ELB

Tags: caching, nginx, amazon-elb

I've got nginx sitting between ELBs. I've got a couple application pools behind an ELB that nginx passes traffic back to and I want to cache static content. My problem is nginx doesn't appear to be caching any responses. This is the cache configuration:

```
proxy_cache_path  /usr/share/nginx/cache/app levels=1:2 keys_zone=cms-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path /usr/share/nginx/cache/;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://cms-pool;
    proxy_cache cms-cache;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
  }
```

After some reading I found there might be some headers causing the issue but after hiding the obvious ones I had no luck and ended up breaking the application since I was hiding all the backend cookies. These are the headers I tried removing:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
```

I'm at a loss right now as to why requests are not being cached, here's an output from curl of the headers that came through with the above header configuration (the cookies and such were set from nginx/elb in front of nginx):

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-length: 6821
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 16 Nov 2014 19:25:41 GMT
ETag: W/"6821-1415964130000"
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Fri, 14 Nov 2014 11:22:10 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.7.6
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=4BB7AB49169E74EC05060FB9839BD30C2CB1D0E43D90837DC593EB2BA783FB372E90B6F6F575D13C6567102032557C76E00B1F5DB0B520CF929C3B81327C1D259A9EA5C73771C4EA3DB6390EB40484EDF56491135B;PATH=/
Set-Cookie: frontend=CgAAi1Ro+jUDNkZYAwMFAg==; path=/
```

---

**Update** I found that the above wasn't entirely accurate as there's a 302 that directs a user to login which hits another backend that doesn't have static resources, as such the headers above are coming from the login backend. I adjusted the URI to point to just the images but no caching is occurring. I'm using the following location block:

```
  location /app/images {
    proxy_pass  http://cms-pool/app/images;
    proxy_cache cms-cache;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
  }
```

These are the headers which are coming through now:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-length: 12700
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 09:25:38 GMT
ETag: "0cd80ce9afecf1:0"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 17:05:06 GMT
Server: nginx/1.7.6
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=4BB7AB49169E74EC05060FB9839BD30C2CB1D0E43D638163025E92245C6C6E40197CA48C5B22F3E8FDA53365109BC1C16C808322881855C100D4AC54E5C0EC6CDE91B96151F66369C7B697B04D2C08439274033D81;PATH=/
Set-Cookie: tscl-frontend=CgAK1FRpvxI4b0bQAwMEAg==; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a wobbly implementation of HTTP caching headers in what's behind ELB.

Per [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (HTTP 1.1) :

> Pragma directives MUST be **passed through by a proxy or gateway
> application, regardless of their significance** to that application,
> since the directives might be applicable to all recipients along the
> request/response chain.

> HTTP/1.1 caches SHOULD treat "Pragma: no-cache" **as if the client had
> sent "Cache-Control: no-cache"**. No new Pragma directives will be
> defined in HTTP.

> Note: because the meaning of "Pragma: no-cache **as a response
> header field is not actually specified**, it does not provide a
> reliable replacement for "Cache-Control: no-cache" in a response

The `Pragma: no-cache` header doesn't mean anything in an HTTP reply because it's behaviour is **unspecified** by RFCs.

But as nginx acts as a (reverse) proxy in your case, it will honor the header as if it was `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to maintain compatibility with HTTP 1.0 protocol's Pragma header defined in [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-44).

It will also pass it through client's response headers as it doesn't have to suppose anything about the actual meaning of it.

So either correct this bad implementation or append `Pragma` header to `proxy_ignore_headers` and `proxy_hide_header` directives.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I did a little digging and determined this header was being sent from another backend pool which doesn't have static resources (302). I adjusted the uri to point to just the static content but no caching is occurring, I'll update the question with details shortly.

Comment: @Ashex Post your full nginx configuration with the update. The `Set-Cookie` header is still present in headers so nginx may not be using the location you think he is.

Comment: I've posted the full nginx configuration, the Set-Cookie header is being set by a ELB which is in front of nginx. General architecture is as follows:


External ELB - Nginx - Backend ELBs - App servers

Comment: @Ashex All right. Your configuration seems OK to me, how are you testing that cache is being hit or not ?

Comment: I'm loading the page in incognito chrome with the inspector open and set to not cache. After I load a page I check if any content showed up under /usr/share/nginx/cache (checking both cache and app) as from the [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path) there should be a temporary file/folder created there.

Comment: @Ashex Does nginx user have rights to read & write this directory ? Do you have errors in error log ?

Comment: directories are 755 with nginx as user/group owner.

Comment: I added the Cache-Status header and the message is MISS when I use curl to hit a image directly.